# A special property of $\limsup$ in $\ell_1$

Tags: functional-analysis, banach-spaces

Let $w$ be any element in $\ell_1$, and $(w_n)$ be a bounded sequence in $\ell_1$ that converge to 0 pointwise. I want to prove 
 $$\limsup\limits_{n\to\infty}\|w_n-w\|_{1}=\limsup\limits_{n\to\infty}\|w_n\|_1+\|w\|_1$$
please help me to prove this . Thanks.

Comment: The inequality $\leqslant$ is immediate from the triangle inequality. So it remains to see $\geqslant$. Fix $\varepsilon > 0$. Choose $K$ so large that $$\sum_{k=K}^\infty \lvert w^{(k)}\rvert < \frac{\varepsilon}{4}.$$ Choose $N$ so large that for $n \geqslant N$ and $k \leqslant K$ ...

Comment: @ Daniel Fischer, may be you write an answer, I can not complete the proof. Thanks

Comment: @ Dear Daniel Fischer may I have your email adders? thank you

Comment: MO copy of the question: http://mathoverflow.net/questions/176877/property-of-limsup-in-ell-1

Comment: I wonder what is the origin of this problem.

Answer (score 2):

This is basically continuation of the solution suggested in [Daniel Fischer's comment](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/875848/a-special-property-of-limsup-in-ell-1#comment1806653_875848).

I will use notation $(w^{(n)})$ for the sequence of elements of $\ell_1$. They are sequences, I will use $w^{(n)}_k$ for the $k$-th term of the $n$-th sequence.

We want to show $$\limsup_{n\to\infty} \|w^{(n)}-w\|_1 = \limsup_{n\to\infty} \|w^{(n)}\|_1 + \|w\|_1.$$

---

From triangle inequality we have
$$\newcommand{\norm}[1]{\|#1\|}
\norm{w^{(n)}-w} \le \norm{w^{(n)}}+\norm{w}.$$
This yields
$$\limsup_{n\to\infty} \norm{w^{(n)}-w} \le \limsup_{n\to\infty} (\norm{w^{(n)}}+\norm{w})
\le \\
\le \limsup_{n\to\infty} \norm{w^{(n)}}+ \limsup_{n\to\infty} \norm{w}
= \limsup_{n\to\infty} \norm{w^{(n)}}+ \norm{w}.$$
(Note that this part works for any norm, we did not use any special property of $\ell_1$-norm.)

---

Let $\newcommand{\ve}\varepsilon\ve>0$.

Since we know that $w\in\ell_1$, there exists $K$ such that
$$\newcommand{\abs}[1]{|#1|}
\sum_{k\ge K} \abs{w_k} < \frac\ve4.$$

Now the sequence $(w^{(n)})$ converges pointwise to $0$. This implies that for each $k\le K$ the sequence $(w^{(n)}_k)_{n=1}^\infty$ converges to $0$.<sup>1</sup>Therefore there exists $N$ such that
$$n\ge N, k\le K \qquad\Rightarrow\qquad \abs{w^{(n)}_k} < \frac\ve{4K}.$$

Now we can use these estimates and reverse triangle inequality to get
$$
\begin{align}
\norm{w^{(n)}-w}_1
&= \sum_{k=1}^\infty \abs{w^{(n)}_k - w_k}\\
&= \sum_{k<K} \abs{w^{(n)}_k - w_k} + \sum_{k\ge K} \abs{w^{(n)}_k - w_k} \\
&\ge \sum_{k<K} \abs{w_k} - \sum_{k<K} \abs{w^{(n)}_k} + \sum_{k\ge K} \abs{w^{(n)}_k} - \sum_{k\ge K} \abs{w_k} \\
&\ge \norm{w}_1 - \frac\ve4 -\frac\ve4+\norm{w^{(n)}}_1-\frac\ve4-\frac\ve4 \\
&= \norm{w}_1 + \norm{w^{(n)}}_1 - \ve
\end{align}
$$
for $n\ge N$.

Now we can apply $\limsup$ on both sides to get
$$\limsup_{n\to\infty} \norm{w^{(n)}-w}_1 \ge \norm{w}_1 + \limsup_{n\to\infty} \norm{w^{(n)}}_1 - \ve.$$
Since this is true for every $\ve>0$, we get
$$\limsup_{n\to\infty} \norm{w^{(n)}-w}_1 \ge \norm{w}_1 + \limsup_{n\to\infty} \norm{w^{(n)}}_1.$$

---

<sup>1</sup> In fact, it is true for each $k$. But since we want choose the same $N$ which works for several sequences, we can only take finitely many sequences.